# fatal error: module 'firebase_core' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Just created a new flutter project, added google-services-info.plist file to iOS and added firebase_core to pubspec.yaml. Ran the project and got this error. 
`Error: fatal error: module 'firebase_core' not found  @import firebase_core;`

I have searched a lot on the stack overflow and gitlab. Tried all the workarounds like flutter clean, update repo, delete pod and reinstall pod but still got no success in resolving this error.

This has blocked me for 5 days. Unable to find anything on this.
Please help.

Link to my project on GitHub. : https://github.com/infonotics/stocklyticsSO
Do add your own googleService-Info.plist file to the Runner folder. I have removed my file for security reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32):

I assume you have tried opening the ios project in xcode. When opening the project in XCode, make sure you open the file with the **.xcworkspace** extension instead of the one with **.xcodeproj** and then build again.

Comment: Occam's Razor Thanks

Comment: This is actually very interesting, The Nobel Price Committee should give a special Nuts award to Apple for giving ambiguous names, icons, and folder structures in different places in the same project and making the developers go nuts.

Answer (score 27):

I had this issue and here is how I fixed it.
cd ios folder and open the Podfile
and add this line
`pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true`
save the file and run pod install

[here is a link to the github answer that helped me](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/6339#discussioncomment-3304918).

Comment: I though I had that already based on another stack overflow question, but I had `FireBaseCoreInternal`. Not the same thing, make sure to double check

Comment: This worked for me. 
This should be an accepted answer, I guess

Answer (score 9):

1. add below line in podfile   `pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true` after `target 'yourprojectname' do`
2. remove podfile.lock
3. reinstall pod `pod install` in ios dir
4. and above error will gone...

Answer (score 3):

If got any error when open xcode,ignore it and do below step.
Type of error: any module firebase not found..(in my case, firebase_core not found) at **GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m**)

**1.0.** flutter clean (VS Code)

**2.0.** flutter pub get (VS Code)

**3.0.** open ios emulator (VS Code)

**4.0.** flutter run (VS Code)

**5.0** done compile

**6.0.** close emulator

**6.0.** open ios folder using xcode  (XCODE)

**7.0.** make sure iphone SE(2nd generation) or any device is selected during
compiling (XCODE)

**8.1.** begin compile (XCODE)

**9.2** error gone and done.

**Podfile**

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The iOS version in deployment info has to match with the version declared in the Podfile.

```
platform :ios, '12.4'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

run pod install in the ios folder of your flutter app

1. open terminal
2. cd "your-project"/ios
3. pod install

Answer (score 2):

You need to download and update the packages in the Podfile.

1. Open Terminal
2. cd ./ios
3. pod update

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue for 3 days then i found out the root cause was
i was running on M1
so my error got solved after following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/running-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Its always a tense moment to try everything and if something does not work.

Tried ffi solution, recreating ios folder via flutter create also did not work.

Finally, it worked by closing xcode , flutter clean and then the usual.

One point to note was Identity and Type should be set to Absolute path. I am not sure if that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using flavors and forgot to select the right scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened when using Firebase authentication.

Before that, while setting up Firebase for iOS initially *(i.e. pod installing for `@@react-native-firebase/app`)* I have gotten the following error: `'The Swift pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal' depends upon 'GoogleUtilities', which does not define modules'`. I have solved it by adding `pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true;` in the Podfile as it is suggested when error displayed.

For the `Module 'FirebaseCore' not found` error, following method worked for me:

- Adding this line in Podfiles: `pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true`
- At the project root directory: `cd ios && pod install --repo-update`
- Rebuild project: `cd .. && npx react-native run-ios`

Related part of my Podfiles at the end:

```
 target 'MyApp' do
   config = use_native_modules!

   # Flags change depending on the env values.
   flags = get_default_flags()

   pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
   pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
```

My setup:

```
OS: macOS Big Sur 11.7.10
Mac: MacBook Pro 13'' Mid 2014
Xcode: 13.2.1
React Native: 0.72.6
@react-native-firebase/app: 18.6.1
@react-native-firebase/auth: 18.6.1
```